# 10 x and y? What does this mean?

Tags: meaning

I gave him 10 iPads and Computers

Does this mean I gave him 10 ipads and 10 computers or Computers + Ipads = 10?

Sources if any?

Comment: It is somewhat ambiguous, but probably means a total of 10 items.

Comment: English is not Math. So even if you set up a distributive arrangement of 10 (iPads and Computers), the reader would figure a total of 10 in some combination. Or else, the reader figures you specified how many iPads but left us hanging with other computers in plural?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I read it as 10 iPads and an unspecified number of computers but however you read it it's very sloppily written. Completely ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

It's ambiguous.  It could mean you gave him 10 iPads and 10 Computers.  For example if it there was a kit for new employees, so every person got exactly one of each so 'iPad and computer' acts like a single thing.

It could also mean you gave him 10 iPads and an unspecified number of computers.  For example, if you let him just grab old computers from storage but you didn't count because they were old and unimportant.  But you had to buy the iPads so you knew exactly how many there were.

I'd be very surprised if it meant that you gave something like 3 iPads and 7 Computers.  i+C=10 makes sense in math terms, but it's not the most obvious interpretation of the statement.

Comment: Agreed. Ambiguous without further explanation or context; but I think if I ever said this sentence I would mean 10 iPads and 10 computers.

Comment: To highlight how it s ambiguous, I disagree with your ordering of most to least likely. I think the second paragraph is the lest likely explanation. In that scenario, I would say "I gave him 10 iPads and some computers," or "I gave  him computers and 10 iPads." Meanwhile, I find the explanation that would surprise you would be only slightly less likely than your first explanation. It would depend on context. If it is something that goes as a set, 10 of each. if it is somethings that can serve a similar purpose, 10 total is equally likely.